# HIgh traffic site bandwidth & concurrency.. facebook, yahoo, etc

Tags: bandwidth, performance

What is considered a high concurrency, bandwidth level? Anyone know the traffic level at facebook, yahoo, ebay, or google? How much are they getting? 100,000 concurrency? 1,000,000 req per sec?

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the real question?

Answer (score 4):

I have worked on websites that handles 20+ million page views a day.  At that time we would push over 500Mb in peak times.  I would suggest if you are really interested high volume traffic websites and how they scale I recommend watching the Velocity videos from this years Velocity '09.  There were many discussions on scaling large scale web systems from the names you mention.  It takes me back to the old Web Monsters/Ad Monsters days during the .com days.  Another good resource for this topic is http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 2):

Most have distributed data centres around the world, often more than one per country so I doubt most of these organisations know exactly what level of concurrency they achieve themselves but it's safe to say that each of those four you mentioned will be dealing with several hundred thousand concurrent users globally at any one time.

Is there a more specific question you had in mind or is there any other string you'd like measured? :)

Answer (score 2):

When I worked for MySpace we didn't have a way to track how many concurrent users we had.  There wasn't anything that could parse that much weblog data.  About all we could go by was how many adds were being served/number of ads per page.  That broke down to 2+ Billion page views per day.  At that rate, if an even number of page views were gotten over the day, that would be ~23k page views per second.

Obviously the site usage was more bell curved than flat, but that gives you a starting number.

(Do keep in mind I haven't worked for MySpace for 2 years now.)